# How can we see our progress towards the next Socratic badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges

The **Socratic badge** is a gold, and we get it when 100 questions with score > 0 and maintain a positive question record, obtainable multiple times

When someone does not have it, then we can see how we're doing.  When someone already has it, then how can we see our progress towards the next one?

Comment: I can not understand your point. Question tab ??

Comment: I have one socratic gold badge in MSE. And I am running for two. But I can not know how much I run.

Comment: Oh, there's far more to it than just positive questions.  The positive question record is a fun thing to try to calculate.

Comment: That's right. When we have no, then we can know through "next badge".

Comment: So, you're really asking for us to make it possible to track badges that you've already gotten **if** they're repeatable? That seems like a reasonable request.

Comment: @Catija : If I understand the point, then now it is impossible. So I am in the state that I ask the such tracking tool. Yes. If you do that, I am happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/outdoors/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges), its possible to see the number of days that count towards the next badge, and in theory when you have 200 of them, you will get your next Socratic badge.

However, since deleted questions aren't in the query the number of days is overestimated. I had 207 positive days when I got my second Socratic badge. Also if your positive question record gets too low you won't be eligible, but if you already have one Socratic badge, then the odds of that are low.